# Regular Expression for NRIC/FIN in Singapore

Tags: regex

I want to check the user input data for NRIC/FIN in Singapore is right or not.

Is `[A-Z] [0-9]{7} [A-Z]` the right regex? Do I need to check the first character being `S`/`F`/`T`/`G`? Please let me know if I need to check for other case.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Use your favourite search engine `NRIC singapore`. Check the [wikepedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Registration_Identity_Card#Structure_of_the_NRIC_number.2FFIN). ... Profit!

Comment: What about permanent residents ^ ^ ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like this is what you are looking for:

```
^[STFG]\d{7}[A-Z]$
```

As per [Wikipedia NRIC/FIN article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Registration_Identity_Card).

> The structure of the NRIC number/FIN is `#0000000@` where: 
>   `#` - This
>   is a letter that can be `S`, `T,` `F` or `G` depending on the status
>   of the holder.
>  `0000000` - This is a 7 digit serial number assigned to
>   the document holder
>  `@` - This is the checksum letter calculated based
>   on `#` and `0000000`.

Perhaps, you would like to make it case-insensitive (`(?i)^[STFG]\d{7}[A-Z]$`).

Also, if you want to validate that code further, checking if it is a foreigner's or Singapore citizen's ID, you'd need a different regex.

Answer (score 1):

`

```js
function nricVal(){
    var ic=document.getElementByID("nric").value;
    if(!ic.match(/^[STFG]\d{7}[A-Z]$/)){
       alert("Invalid NRIC");
       return false;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Please Check the question. There is no tag for jquery or javascript. Do not assume things and answer in a hurry. Please answer according to the tags given to a question.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew has answered correctly.. But while applying the regex in the code, need an exact format. So I have given it.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution is correct. But to be precise, the checksum (last letter of the identification number) is not A-Z, it is A-J or Z.

**Local NRIC regex:**

```
^[ST]\d{7}[A-JZ]$
```

**Foreign NRIC regex:**

```
^[FG]\d{7}[A-JZ]$
```

Comment: That is no longer true - the checksum letter can now be A-Z.

Answer (score -1):

^[STFGstfg]\d{7}[a-zA-Z]$

here u go

Comment: No explanation and same answer( or not a significatif addition to ) as already given answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29743250/5468463